# Get the last scroll from a FlatList and redirect

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, onpress

I'm creating an Onboarding screen. I don't want to add buttons to this onboarding screen, the only way to go to the next page is by swiping. Although I need to have a way to get when the user is at the last screen, and when he swipes right, I will be redirecting him to the login screen.

This is the last screen on the app:
[image]

When the user swipes right from this screen, I want to make a redirect, like a function or a onPress.

This is the onboarding code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { 
    Container,
    FlatListContainer
} from './styles';
import {
    FlatList,
    Animated,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import OnboardingData from '../../utils/onboarding';
import { OnboardingItem } from '../../components/OnboardingItem';
import { Paginator } from '../../components/Paginator';

export function Onboarding(){

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const onboardingDataRef = useRef(null);

    const viewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }: any) => {
        setCurrentIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
    }).current;

    const viewConfig = useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 }).current;

    return (
        <Container>
            <FlatListContainer>
                <FlatList 
                    data={OnboardingData} 
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <OnboardingItem image={item.image} title={item.title} description={item.description}/>}
                    horizontal
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    pagingEnabled={true}
                    bounces={false}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
                    onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } }}], {
                        useNativeDriver: false
                    })}
                    scrollEventThrottle={32}
                    onViewableItemsChanged={viewableItemsChanged}
                    viewabilityConfig={viewConfig}
                    ref={onboardingDataRef}
                />
            </FlatListContainer>

            <Paginator data={OnboardingData} scrollX={scrollX} scrollY={scrollY} currentIndex={currentIndex}/>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought about it, and the old method wouldnt work, as there isnt a viewableItem beyond the final page.

You could use the FlatList `onScroll` function to listen for swipes. When at the final page and a scroll event occurs, verify that it wasnt an attempt to go to the previous page and then navigate. e.g.

```js
// store previous scroll values
const prevScroll = useRef({});

// scrollX, scrollY already contains the data 
useEffect(()=>{
  let isLastIndex = currentIndex == onBoardingData.length  - 1;
  let isScrollingToNextPage =  scrollX > prevScroll.current.x
  if( isLastIndex && isScrollingToNextPage ){ 
      props.navigation.navigate("Login");
      return
    }
  // store offsets
  prevScroll.current = { x:scrollX, y:scrollY}
},[scrollX, scrollY])
```

If you would like for the old method to work you could just add an additional page (could be an empty view or a view with a small message)

--------OLD--------

Im assuming that `OnBordingData` is an array since you're passing it to the Flatlist data prop. If so, then couldnt you add a conditional to your `viewableItemsChanged` so that it goes to the login screen when at `index > OnBoardingData.length - 1`? e.g

```js
const viewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }: any) => {
        const index = viewableItems[0].index;
        if(index >= OnBoardinData.length -1){
          // be sure to add props as a parameter to OnBoarding function
          props.navigation.navigate("Login");
          return
        } 
        setCurrentIndex(index);
    }).current;
```

--------OLD--------

Comment: I already have data on my onScroll, how will I proceed then?

Comment: Sorry. I have never used `Animated.Event` and when I was reading your code I glossed over the stuff I didnt know. After figuring out what it does, I think you could just use `useEffect` with `[scrollX,scrollY]` as dependencies. Because `useEffect` doesnt have access to the previous dependency values, you would need a ref to hold the previous values and then do the comparisons. I've updated my answer to reflect

Comment: Both of the methods didn't work, the first one doens't work at all since, scrollX and scrollY are for animations. And the old method always triggers on the last screen, then the user won't see it!